# Is the Whitehead product $[\iota_2, \eta] : \pi_4\mathbb{S}^2$ trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $\iota_2 : \pi_2\mathbb{S}^2$ be a generator and let $\eta : \pi_3\mathbb{S}^2$ be the Hopf map.

The Whitehead product $[\iota_2, [\iota_2, \iota_2]] : \pi_4\mathbb{S}^2$ must be trivial, because $$[\iota_2, [\iota_2, \iota_2]] = [\iota_2, 2\eta] = 2[\iota_2, \eta]$$

But what is $[\iota_2, \eta]$? Is it 0 or 1?

Comment: I suspect now that every Whitehead product landing in $\pi_4\mathbb{S}^2$ vanishes, because the suspension $\pi_4\mathbb{S}^2 \to \pi_5\mathbb{S}^3$ is an isomorphism. Right?